Authorize.Net throws "User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values" but works in sandbox. All credentials are verified as correct
I've test it for valid card and also few times I recreate transaction keys but it helpless.
I checked all forums about this.
Ive got 007 code error which says
Posting a live account's API Login ID and Transaction Key to the test environment at https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api. For live accounts, please post to https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api instead.
Posting a test account's API Login ID and Transaction Key to the live environment at https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api. For test accounts, please post to https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api instead.
The API Login ID or Transaction Key have errors.
Im sure all my creds are correct, I cheched it 100 times.
first of all I create customer payment profile if it does not exists already
    def create_customer_profile(cls, user: User, merchant_auth):

        if not user.customer_profile_id:
            customer_data = {
                "merchantCustomerId": str(user.id),
                "email": user.email,
            }
            create_customer_profile = apicontractsv1.createCustomerProfileRequest()
            create_customer_profile.merchantAuthentication = merchant_auth
            create_customer_profile.profile = apicontractsv1.customerProfileType(
                **customer_data
            )

            controller = createCustomerProfileController(create_customer_profile)
            controller.execute()
            response = controller.getresponse()
            if response.messages.resultCode == "Ok":
                user.customer_profile_id = response.customerProfileId
                user.save()
                return response.customerProfileId
            else:
                raise TransactionCanceled(
                    message=str(response.messages.message[0]["text"].text)
                )
        return user.customer_profile_id

after that I try to create customer payment profile with all credit card and billing data
@classmethod
    def create_customer_payment_profile(
        cls, card_details, billing_address, user: User, default: bool
    ):
        merchant_auth = cls.merchant_auth()
        payment = apicontractsv1.paymentType()
        credit_card = apicontractsv1.creditCardType()
        credit_card.cardNumber = card_details["card_number"]
        credit_card.expirationDate = card_details["mm_yy"]
        credit_card.cardCode = card_details["cvv"]
        payment.creditCard = credit_card

        profile = apicontractsv1.customerPaymentProfileType()
        profile.payment = payment
        profile.billTo = apicontractsv1.customerAddressType()
        profile.billTo.address = billing_address["address_1"]
        profile.billTo.city = billing_address["city"]
        profile.billTo.state = billing_address["state"]
        profile.billTo.zip = billing_address["postal_code"]
        create_payment_profile_request = (
            apicontractsv1.createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest()
        )
        create_payment_profile_request.merchantAuthentication = merchant_auth
        create_payment_profile_request.paymentProfile = profile

        create_payment_profile_request.customerProfileId = str(
            cls.create_customer_profile(user, merchant_auth)
        )
        create_payment_profile_request.defaultPaymentProfile = default
        controller = createCustomerPaymentProfileController(
            create_payment_profile_request
        )

        controller.execute()
        response = controller.getresponse()
        return response.customerPaymentProfileId

The body is like?
{
  "payment_method": {
    "card_holder": "name surname",
    "card_number": "valid card numbers",
    "mm_yy": "valid exp",
    "cvv": "valid cvv"
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "address_1": "valid adr1",
    "city": "valid City",
    "state": "valdi state",
    "postal_code": "valid postal_code"
  }
}

